# PointPickingCallback may give wrong point position when add 3D text to the cloud viewer

Tags: pcl

I tried the pcd_viewer.cpp(https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/tools/pcd_viewer.cpp) code and it worked well. But when I changed the 3D text scale in the *pp_callback* as below, the callback may give completely wrong point position.

```
p->addText3D<pcl::PointXYZ> (idx_string, pos, 5/*0.0005*/, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, idx_string);  // changed 0.0005 to 5 to make the text big enough to see
```

Here is the console log. Even I picked different point in the point cloud, the callpack still gave the wrong point which does not exist in the point cloud.
[See console logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d03yZ.jpg)

My environment is as below:

```
Windows 10 x64   VisualStudio 2019
PCL 1.8.1 and PCL 1.13.1
CPU&GPU: AMD ryzen5 4650u
```

If I use `removeAllShapes()` from the viewer before I pick a point, the callback will give the right position of the point all the time. But I realy need to add some text and shape in the viewer.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.